# Mirror network traffic for traffic interception

Tags: networking, network-programming, libpcap, winpcap

I want to develop an application where all traffic from network segment gets mirrored onto a windows station in order to be able to see all tcp-ip request/response data (filtering).

I know that it should be possible using WinPcap to capture all packets but problem in this case would be that I would have to implement all the processing needed to be able to distinguish tcp data streams (e.g. handshaking, closing, retransmissions, reordering, maybe others ?). I need the stream of data because I will be doing application level (e.g. http) filtering.

I wonder if there is a driver/solution somewhere that provides me tcp data stream, solution that could be used on a gateway machine or using port mirroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, in WinPCap, you can define something called [filter](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__language.html).
That filter filters out all the traffic except the type that you specify, so if you want to capture HTTP traffic only, I'd suggest you make a filter on `TCP Port 80` or any other port you're using for HTTP.

Once you've captured these packets, you can check the payload of the TCP, parse the HTTP header and do whatever you wish according to your system's policy.

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20501/TCP-Session-Reconstruction-Tool) if you want to familiarize yourself with how to use WinPCap and how to use filters(in this example they're capturing TCP traffic in general, you should add to their filter "port 80").

Comment: Tnx for the link. It seems that libnids seems to do just what I need.